# When is the change of UI reflected in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display "Now loading" just after starting processing. So I change a variable(`tkinter.StringVar`) linked to `tkinter.Label` by using `set()` method. However, the change are reflected after finishing next processing. Moreover, If I call `loading()` normally, the UI is displayed after all process has done. To display the window in advance, I have to use `self.after(time, loading)`. Why? Here is code snippet.

```
import glob
import os
import tkinter
import time

class Application(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.filepaths = []
        self.var = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.var.set("No Info")
        self.info = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable = self.var)
        self.info.pack()
        self.after(1000, self.loading)


    def loading(self):
        self.var.set("Now Loading")
        self.dirrecur(".")
        print(self.filepaths)
        self.var.set("No Info")

    def dirrecur(self, dirname):
        contents = glob.glob(dirname + "/*")
        for content in contents:
            if os.path.isdir(content):
                self.dirrecur(content)
            else:
                print(content)
                self.filepaths.append(content)

Application().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All screen updates happen in response to events. If the event loop isn't running it can't process those events. By using after, you're giving the event loop a chance to process "redraw" events before calling your function. Note that tkinter is single-threaded, so no events can be processed while other code is running.

Tkinter has a generic widget method named [update_idletasks](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) that allows the event loop to process all "idle" tasks, which includes refreshing the display.

Comment: `update_idletasks` is useful. Thank you. So you mean, in this code, until `__init__` has finished and `mainloop()` is called, the widgets are not displayed? If I want to draw some event before `mainloop()`, I have to use `after()` or `update_idletaks()` or to set function with widget?

Comment: After calling `mainloop()`, I cannot call any function, can I? So when is the event loop running and when is the event loop not running?

Comment: @q2ven: correct: mainloop should be the last statement your program executes after startup; it won't return until the main window has been destroyed. While you can technically have other code after it, the window will be gone. Once it starts, it is already running so to speak, but it is single threaded and can only handle one event at a time.

Comment: that in this code, until `__init__` has finished and `mainloop()` is called, the widgets are not displayed is correct?

Comment: @q2ven: they are made visible when you either call `update`, `update_idletasks`, or start `mainloop`. All of those cause events in the event queue to be processed (though `update_idletasks` only processes "idle" events)